# Laravel Notification - Call to a member function routeNotificationFor() on string

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-notification

Laravel 5.5

Controller

```
public function sendBookingSms(){
  $checkState = session()->get('checkState');
  $staffs = Staff::whereIn('staffId',$checkState)->get();
  foreach ($staffs as $staff) {
    $email = str_replace(" ","","44".substr($staff->mobile, 1)).'@mail.mightytext.net';
    Notification::send($email, new NewBooking($email));
  }
  return $staffs;
  session()->forget('checkState');
  return redirect(route('booking.current'))->with('message','Succesfully Send SMS to selected staffs !!');
}
```

NewBooking.php (Notification)

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

When calling this controller I am getting this error.

[image]

$staffs.

```
{  
   "staffId":45,
   "forname":"Eldhose",
   "surname":"John",
   "categoryId":2,
   "email":"devhelloworld@gmail.com",
   "mobile":"07588593278",
   "whatsappNumber":"57656578658",
   "gender":1,
   "address":"Poole",
   "pincode":null,
   "modeOfTransport":1,
   "pickupLocation":"Office",
   "branchId":0,
   "zoneId":1,
   "bandId":1,
   "paymentMode":1,
   "payRateWeekday":10,
   "payRateWeekNight":20,
   "payRateWeekendDay":10,
   "payRateWeekendNight":20,
   "payRateSpecialBhday":11,
   "payRateSpecialBhnight":15,
   "payRateBhday":11,
   "payRateBhnight":15,
   "status":1,
   "deleted_at":null,
   "created_at":"2018-02-26 22:16:44",
   "updated_at":"2018-02-26 22:16:44"
}
```

Please help me on this.... Thanks

Comment: Can u check whether the data is there in staffs and email.

Comment: Yes. Data in staffs array

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Notification::send()** requires the first argument to be an object, usually one that uses the **Notifiable** trait. You pass just a string holding email address, hence the error.

If you simply want to send a notification to given email address, you'll need to use **on-demand notifications**. The following should do the trick:

```
Notification::route('mail', $email)->notify(new NewBooking($email));
```

For more details see the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#sending-notifications

Latest docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications

Comment: But I am using not trait. Please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: I didn't understand why you are calling route from here. can u please tell me more about your answer.

Comment: If you're not using a trait, the code in my answer will work. See docs on the on-demand notifications that I posted. That's what you use when you don't have an object with Notifiable trait but just an email address.

Comment: Route is working in v5.5 in 5.3 there is no notification on demand